# LPD6803 RGB LED Strip with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, led

I purchased a 5 Meter flexible waterproof Digital Addressable RGB LED strip from [Lee's Electronic](http://www.leeselectronic.com/) (A local electronics store). The strip uses LPD6803 ([datasheet](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/LPD6803.pdf)) and I have purchased a 6A 12v power supply.

Adafruit has a [LPD6803 library](https://github.com/adafruit/LPD6803-RGB-Pixels) on github. The library was designed for AdaFrute's [20mm Clear Digital RGB LED Pixels](http://www.adafruit.com/products/307). Using the example code that came with library, I connected power supply and the Arduino UNO

Here is an [image of the connector](http://www.abluestar.com/files/uploads/IMG_3616.JPG) on the RGB LED strip. I connected the C1 (green) to Arduino pin 3 (clock). I connected the S1 (Red) to the Arduino pin 2 (data), and Gnd to the Arduino ground.

After I upload the sketch to the Arduino and connected the power. All the LEDs turn white. I played with the sketch a bit but I was unable to get it to do anything but ALL white.

After some googling I found an alternative libary [FastSPI_LED](http://code.google.com/p/fastspi/) that also supports this chip. Set up the example and had the same problem. All white.

Next looked in to the data sheet and found that this chip uses a 32 zero sequence at before it starts the sequence for the different colors. So I used [ShiftOut](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut) on the arduino and shifted out 32 zeros followed by a sequence of other values. All white.

I'm not sure what to try next. 
Suggestions, comments, thoughts?

Comment: How do you know what the connections are? I looked at the product page for Lee's Electronics but there was nothing - not even a photo. The connections are different to the Adafruit version, and don't seem to bear much resemblance to the IC pin names. Where do you apply V+ and GND? I would guess that possibly the D1 is for data and C1 is clock.  Are you sure it's the LPD6803 and not some other IC? Surely there is some clue that comes with the strip on wiring it up and use?

Comment: The Adafruit version uses a LPD8806 and is different then the one I purchased. but they provide a library for LPD6803 version as well. If you look at the picture, You should see that D1 and L1 have two wires connected to the terminals. These lead to a barrel connector that I connect to a power adapter. This connections was already assembled on purchase. You can also see the chip and its model in the picture. Yes I am sure it is LPD6803.

Comment: Are you sure you have the arduino connected to the input?

Comment: @Craig Yes I am sure that I have connected the arduino to the LED strip lights. I'm NOT sure If I connected it correctly. See above for pin out that I am using.

Comment: I suppose I should have been more clear. When I used a similar strip there were connectors at both ends.  One for input and one to connect to the next strip.  Initially I connected to the output instead of the input and had similar results.

Comment: Just purchased one of these older strips from Amazon:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KNQRJ6E/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and was having some trouble getting it going, but this thread did it. In particular, Craig's last comment about making sure you have the Arduino connected to the right end of the strip--it's directional! Once I hooked my Arduino data and clock pins to the 'other' end of the strip (also where the 12v power leads come in on my strip at least) the LPD6803-RGB-Pexels library worked great.

Answer (score 1):

I have this strand of LEDs/Controllers and I've made it work with the [LPD6803-RGB-Pixels library](https://github.com/adafruit/LPD6803-RGB-Pixels).

To connect the strip correctly:

- Di (Blue Wire) = VCC -> Connect pin: Vin on Arduino.
- Ci (Green Wire) = Data -> Connect to pin: 2 on Arduino.
- St (Red Wire) = Clock -> Connect to pin: 3 on Arduino.
- Li (Black Wire) = GND -> Connect to pin: GND on Arduino.

Once the Arduino is programmed, unplug USB cable, and only use the 12V supply.

Hope this helps.